# Modify the data in method getDataSourceIterator | Sonata Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-2.8

How can I modify the data THE EXPORT ACTION to eliminate an element that does not meet a condition, using the method getDataSourceIterator | Sonata Symfony 2.8  - this example is in the documentation, but it does not explain how to modify data as necessary

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Admin/PersonAdmin.php

class PersonAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    public function getDataSourceIterator()
    {
        $iterator = parent::getDataSourceIterator();
        $iterator->setDateTimeFormat('d/m/Y'); //change this to suit your needs
        return $iterator;
    }
}
```

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_export.html

solve it in this way:

```
public function getDataSourceIterator()
{
    $datagrid = $this->getDatagrid();
    $datagrid->getQuery()->field('state')->equals(APPROVED);
    $datagrid->buildPager();
    $datasource = $this->getModelManager()->getDataSourceIterator($datagrid, $this->getExportFields());
    return $datasource;
}
```

Comment: Solvent that way by doing the query before instantiating the buildPager () and it worked correctly.

Comment: Please ... even if you answer your own question, share your experience with other users by creating a separate answer and mark it as your accepted solution!